# Using command line tools to filter and meet packet flow criteria

Tags: networking, analysis, duration, traffic

I have a pcap file with 8 million packets that I have reduced to a txt file with just three fields: time (in seconds), IP source address, type (of traffic).

I need to extract from this 8 million-line file only those IP addresses that have 100 packets or more, eliminating those addresses which do not meet the 100-packet or more criteria, making the file smaller.

But I need to keep all 3 fields, and all packets in the flow of the remaining addresses (of 100+ packets) in the reduced txt file because I need to calculate the packet flow duration for each IP source address (ending time of flow - beginning time of flow), and keep only those Ip source addresses whose flow duration is 60 seconds or more, thus reducing my file even more.

When I used command line tools to fulfill the first criteria (100 packets or more) I eliminate all packet flow for those addresses. How can I achieve those two conditions using command line tools to be able to automate the process using a bash script? 
Below is a sample of my file to which I need to apply the two criteria. Thank you very much for your help!

> 1385957611.118522 99.61.34.145 TCP
>   1385957859.425248 99.61.34.145 TCP
>   1385958784.632631 99.61.34.145 TCP
>   1385959038.972602 99.61.34.145 TCP
>   1385959481.571627 99.61.34.145 TCP
>   1385860339.225421 37.139.6.111 TCP
>   1385860339.238402 37.139.6.111 TCP
>   1385860339.286538 37.139.6.111 TCP
>   1385860339.379029 37.139.6.111 TCP
>   1385860339.380669 37.139.6.111 TCP
>   1385860339.425247 37.139.6.111 TCP
>   1385860339.556737 37.139.6.111 TCP
>   1385860339.583913 37.139.6.111 TCP
>   1385860339.623861 37.139.6.111 TCP
>   1385857840.419300 103.248.63.253 TCP
>   1385857841.739372 103.248.63.253 TCP
>   1385857848.593171 103.248.63.253 TCP
>   1385857850.411457 103.248.63.253 TCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a combination of awk and xargs to accomplish this. The following script assumes that your data file is organized as one-record-per-line and also that each timestamp is larger than the previous one:

```
awk '{
    line = $0;
    addr = $2;
    addrcount[addr]++;
}
END {
    for (addr in addrcount) {
        if (addrcount[addr] >= 100) {
            print addr;
        }
    }
}' [DATA_FILE] | xargs -P [MAXPROCS] -I 'IP_ADDR' awk '{ if ($2 == "IP_ADDR") { print $0 } }' [DATA_FILE] | awk '{
    timestamp = $1
    addr = $2;
    traffictype = $3;
    if (!(addr in minfor)) {
        minfor[addr] = timestamp;
    }
    maxfor[addr] = timestamp;
    typefor[addr] = traffictype;
}
END {
    for (addr in minfor) {
        print addr, minfor[addr], maxfor[addr], maxfor[addr] - minfor[addr], typefor[addr]
    }
}' | awk '{ if ($4 >= 60) { print $1, $5} }'
```

The first awk bit figures out which IP addresses have 100+ records and prints them, one address per line. This is piped to xargs which runs another awk script that prints only those lines in your file that have those IP addresses. This should prevent you from losing context when trying to filter for 100+ packets. The second-to-last awk script goes through each line in the filtered data and records the minimum timestamp and maximum timestamp, then prints out the difference. It also records the traffic type. The final awk script filters the data such that only those IP addresses with time deltas of more than 60, printing the IP address and traffic type.

Comment: That works great! Thanks.  But the second criteria: From this newly generated file (with only 100+packets IPs) how can I only keep those Ip addresses whose packet-flow duration is more than 60 seconds.  Packet flow duration: final time of flow - initial time of flow for each IP address

Comment: How can it be added to your script: Identify first occurrence of an Ip address (in the file with only 100packet+ addresses), look at the initial time (time field corresponding to first occurrence IPaddress), look at final time of flow, subtract, and if difference >= 60, keep that IP address and its corresponding type field (TCP/UDP/ICMP) and put in a new final file that I can later covert to csv file.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I've updated the script to filter for a time greater than 60 and keep the traffic type. The edits adde the `typefor` array and the final pipe through another awk script.

Comment: Thank you for that update David.  I would like to try it right away; however,   I ran the first script last night, and it works fine, but it is slow. I started it last night, and this morning it was still running, very slowly producing the desired output.  What changes to the logic can be done so it runs faster, so I can also try the second part that you added as well? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You may want to try adding the `xargs -P [maxprocs]` option. This should parallelize the second awk script and may speed that step up considerably. I'd try setting `maxprocs` to be the number of cores in your machine. If it's still too slow, you might want to consider writing a specialized program to do this instead of relying on just standard tools.

Comment: How do I add that option? Do I have to download it, or in the code? Where? Sorry, very inexperienced here. Thank you.

Comment: You may also want to try splitting your original file up and running the script over the smaller files, one after the other. If AWK is using too much memory I imagine that could slow things down a lot and using smaller files should cut down on memory use.

Comment: I updated the script to show where the `xargs -P` would be used.

Comment: My first approach was to split my 822 MB pcap file using editcap into about 800 files because the "sort" command was stalling.  But to meet flow duration >=60 sec criteria, splitting files will also cut flow of packets for the many Ip addresses spread throughout the large pcap file (the same ip address appears on many of the smaller files).  Instead I decided to write to a text file only those 3 fields I needed and use tools to meet other criteria.  But it seems it would not be possible.  I was supposed to try to do this w/o coding and see how much can get done.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: OK so I will run the new script and see.  But you mentioned something about matching to number of cores in my machine, so replace [maxprocs] brackets included for number of cores in my machine?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, replace `[maxprocs]` with the number of cores in your machine. If you're using Linux you should be able to run `lscpu` to find that number. If you're using Mac OS or FreeBSD you can run `sysctl -n hw.ncpu` to get the number of cores.

Comment: Thank you I did.  Replaced [maxprocs] with 4.  its running now. thxs

Comment: It took about an hour, but got a slightly reduced IP address list than without  >=60 sec filter.  Thanks so much!